# Unit delay's magnitude

Tags: matlab, simulink

What is the magnitude of delay in sec offered by unit delay (simulink block) for following condition?
Configuration parameters are variable step with ode45 solver.
Max step size is 1/60 and min step size is auto.

In delay block sample time is kept as 0.5s.
Input processing is set as 'Elements as channels (sample based)'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using discrete blocks as you have mentioned "Unit Delay". In that case, the delay caused is your sample time. ie here it is 0.5s. 
Usually Matlab will go for a discreet solver unless you have explicitly mentioned 'ode45' solver. Also, stepsize of solver wont affect the delay

Comment: My system is continuous. There are no discrete blocks in system.

Comment: If you're using the Unit Delay then you must have a discrete block.  If you don't have discrete blocks then you need to tell us exactly which block you have set to have a sample time of 0.5s.

Answer (score 1):

Simply your sampling time. But If you have some informations that we do not know I will give you a way to measure it.

In you model add 2 Scopes. Assign one of these Scopes' input as `output` of the Delay Block. Other Scope's input will be `input` of the `Delay Block`.

Run the simulation and open the graph results of Scopes. There you go. You can see how much delay your Delay Block caused.